# Android Google map move/animate camera doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a fragment with a `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` in it.  In `onResume` I'm doing this:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(position)
                        .zoom(zoom)
                        .build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });
```

When it first loads, this works fine.  If I then load a new fragment and go back to the map, `animateCamera` is called but does nothing - the map reverts to the default view centered on 0,0 - and also switches from satellite to standard.  The lat/lon and zoom values are fine when it gets called as I can see in the debugger.

I have tried `moveCamera` instead of `animateCamera` as well as several variations I've found researching the problem to no effect.  I also tried moving everything to `onCreate` with no apparent change. There are no errors in logcat.  Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe setting OnMapLoadedCallback at onMapReady

Comment: @pablobu I don't understand, can you explain further?

Comment: check my answer